# How to Get a Stable, Working Dual Boot of Ubuntu 18.04 on Macbook Pro 2019

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kernel, mac, macbook-pro

I have been trying to get an Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot on my Macbook Pro, 13" to work for multiple months now and I've probably put about 12 hours of work into it so far. I am doing stuff with ROS melodic and need 18.04. I will try to explain the main issues I've been having.

First, I just followed any old tutorial on the internet. After having some issues with rEFInd and the `nomodeset` thing that I had to add, I got the live USB to work. However, it did not detect the NVMe in my computer, only the USB it was plugged in to. I tried to fix this for a while, to no avail. I instead opted to install actual Ubuntu on another USB and make that bootable. That went surprisingly easily. However, I think I unplugged the ethernet by accident so it messed up all the drivers, including wireless, mouse, trackpad, etc, but hopefully, that's a separate issue.

Having Ubuntu running off of a USB is obviously not very optimal. It is slow, less storage space, and generally doing anything too fast freezes the whole thing up. Thus, I tried again to figure out the NVMe problem. I found a number of posts that blamed it on the T2 chip and [said the issue was resolved with kernel 5.1.15](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/71#issuecomment-507325112). I then tried two approaches:

1. Make a live USB with the correct kernel version on it (5.1.15). I found [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), which seems to be deprecated and I couldn't get to work. I tried UNetBootin and I think one other than I can't remember, but they both didn't seem to let you change the kernel (maybe I just didn't try hard enough?).
2. Update the kernel in Ubuntu then make a live USB of that (because I read somewhere that second step is possible). I used UKUU to update the kernel and I didn't quite mean to but I selected 5.4 as the one to use (I really wanted 5.3 or even just 5.1.15). It finally worked, showing that it was going to boot to `vmlinuz-5.4`..., but once I got past rEFInd, within less than a second, I got the "`kernel panic not syncing vfs`" message. Pressing shift or any other key combo doesn't even bring up a terminal, so I have no idea how to fix that. I'm not super concerned about my data as all my code was on Github and I had nothing else on there.

Basically, what this all comes down to is, firstly, has anyone else had this much trouble dual booting Ubuntu with the new Macbook Pros. Second, how can I fix this? What would be the best approach to getting a live USB with the updated kernel so I can then install Ubuntu onto my NVMe? Are there other fixes I should try? I can't do Ubuntu 19 or 16 because I need ROS and some packages to work on it, and ROS doesn't like Ubuntu 19 and some of the packages don't like Ubuntu 16.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kernel 5.3.0 is officially available for 18.04 through the package `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge`. I don't know how "stable" it is considered to be, but it can't be worse than what you get through UKUU...

Comment: @fkraiem Ok, I will try that. Do you know how I can make a Live USB installer out of my Ubuntu after I do that (so I can then install Ubuntu onto my actual SSD)?